# SOQL and Simple Salesforce query

Tags: mysql, salesforce, soql, simple-salesforce

I have a custom object "DisableUserTask__c" with a field "DisableOn__c."  I'm at trying to come up with a query to find any "DisableUserTask__c" task with a "DisableOn__c" field that is passed, but I can't seem to come up with a query.

When I run a query just to get a task, the query "DisableOn__c" field comes back with a return in my timezone with the format: u'2015-07-28T21:00:00.000+0000'

I have tried using:

```
"select Name, Project__c, Ownerid, Id, DisableOn__c, User__c from PIXDisableUserTask__c WHERE Status__c = 'Pending' AND DisableOn__c < :Datetime.now()"
```

...but that gives me a malformed query.  I'm very new to database queries like this so I'm pretty stuck.  Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On querying, Salesforce give you the format you are reciving. There is no problem with your query and you can directly use the value you recieved for other operations.

Comment: Hello Rakesh,There does seem to be some problem, because I get a "malformed query" error.

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting a date variable

```
DateTime date1 = System.Now();
"select Name, Project__c, Ownerid, Id, DisableOn__c, User__c from PIXDisableUserTask__c WHERE Status__c = 'Pending' AND DisableOn__c < :date1"
```

Comment: Hello Psymm.  Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure how to use the DateTime line.  I'm using Simple Salesforce Python module so my actual code looks like:         disables = self.sssvc.query("select Name, Project__c, Ownerid, Id, DisableOn__c, User__c from PIXDisableUserTask__c WHERE Status__c = 'Pending' AND DisableOn__c <=:system.now() ")
        return disables  Are you saying I should use the Python datetime module to get a timestamp?